# Kaltura kWidget player working on Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, kaltura

I'm trying to implement a version of Kaltura player for my website. The problem is that when I tried to execute one of the demos that they provide on my Android device didn't worked.

http://html5video.org/kaltura-player/modules/KalturaSupport/tests/SeekApi.qunit.html

How can I make this example works on my Android phone?

Comment: all examples should work on android - please share that model type and the android version we'll check it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

Put this in your MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 


    final PlayerViewController mPlayerView = (PlayerViewController) findViewById( R.id.custom_player );
    mPlayerView.setActivity(this);
    mPlayerView.addComponents(String partnerId, String entryId,this);

}
```

Put this in your xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.kaltura.playersdk.PlayerViewController
    android:id="@+id/custom_player"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp" 
   />
```

Enable internet connection in Manifest file:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Don't  forget to import the following projects in to your project:
1.google-play-services_lib 
2.PlayerSDK
3.CastCompanionLibrary-android.